How to shake a real android device using Appium Python?
I am working on an app that requires to shake in order to show bug reporter menu. How to do this in appium using Python? TouchAction is deprecated so I can not use it. Can someone help?
type here
# perform a series of rapid swipes on the screen to simulate shaking the device
touch_action = TouchAction(driver)
for i in range(5):
    touch_action.press(x=100, y=100).wait(100).move_to(x=200, y=200).release().perform()
    touch_action.press(x=200, y=200).wait(100).move_to(x=100, y=100).release().perform()
time.sleep(1)
# close the app and quit the driver
driver.close_app()

This code did not work as TouchActions is deprecated in Appium v4
